# Unable to connect to SQL Server through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I changed the SQL service account from NT Service\MSSQLSERVER to an AD service account. SQL server  service account has administrator access in server.

But now I am unable to connect to the SQL server. Got the following message
[image]

Comment: What authentication type are you trying to use? What error are you getting when trying to log in?

Comment: I am using windows authentication .

Comment: I'm guessing you can probably connect with Windows Auth via the SQL host IP address (instead of DNS name). You'll also probably be able to connect with SQL Auth (via DNS namre or IP address) As for the current problem, check the SQL log and verify the SPN is getting set correctly. Another possibility: the SQL host may have an issue communicating with the AD server? Yet another possibility is the server date/time setting of the SQL Server host doesn't match that of the AD server.

Comment: Found the issue. Working with the AD team to get it fixed.Solution in the  refrence sites      Source: https://cmatskas.com/fixing-error-cannot-generate-sspi-context-after-changing-sql-service-account/
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811889/how-to-troubleshoot-the-cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the security event logs. If you are using Kerberos then check the logon attempt with Kerberos authentication package.